# Customizing GtkTextTag appearance thru GTK3 CSS stylesheets?

Tags: c, linux, gtk3

I have some `GtkTextTable*mom_tagtable;` which is the tag table of a `GtkTextBuffer *mom_obtextbuf;` (which is shown in two text views `GtkWidget *mom_tview1;` & `GtkWidget*mom_tview2;`). I'm using GTK3.21 on Linux/Debian/Sid and it is for the same (free software, GPLv3) application than in [this other](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39366248/841108) question: the [expjs branch](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/tree/expjs) (on `github`) of the MELT monitor. BTW all the GTK code is in one C99 file [gui.c](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015/blob/expjs/gui.c). I have a few dozen of text tags:

```
static GtkTextTag *mom_tag_toptitle;    // tag for top text
static GtkTextTag *mom_tag_objtitle;    // tag for object title line
static GtkTextTag *mom_tag_objsubtitle; // tag for object subtitle line
static GtkTextTag *mom_tag_idstart;     // tag for first characters of objids
/* etc .... */
```

I don't want to build my GUI using `GtkBuilder` (I prefer coding manually, because most of the code could be later generated by my application). I would like to customize the appearance of the tags and of all my app in the same textual file. It seems that [GTK CSS stylesheets](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html) could be useful.

Actually, it looks that GTK3 has or had several ways to describe the look&feel and theme of an application in textual files ([GtkBuilder](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html) which also defines the GUI and I don't want to have that, [GTK-CSS stylesheets](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/chap-css-overview.html), obsolete Gtk [resource](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-Resource-Files.html) files, obsolete [GtkUIManager](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkUIManager.html), etc...) and that it is transitioning to the GTK CSS framework but the transition did not complete in GTK3.20.

I'm currently initializing these tags using hard-coded look & feel:

```
    mom_tag_toptitle =
      gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (mom_obtextbuf,
                                  "toptitle",
                                  "justification", GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER,
                                  "pixels-above-lines", 2,
                                  "pixels-below-lines", 4,
                                  "foreground", "navy",
                                  "paragraph-background", "lightyellow",
                                  "font", "Helvetica Bold", "scale", 1.5, NULL);
    mom_tag_objtitle =
      gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (mom_obtextbuf,
                                  "objtitle",
                                  "justification", GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER,
                                  "pixels-above-lines", 4,
                                  "pixels-below-lines", 2,
                                  "foreground", "brown",
                                  "font", "Sans Bold",
                                  "paragraph-background", "lightcyan",
                                  "scale", 1.3, NULL);
    mom_tag_objsubtitle =
      gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (mom_obtextbuf,
                                  "objsubtitle",
                                  "justification", GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER,
                                  "pixels-above-lines", 1,
                                  "pixels-below-lines", 1,
                                  "foreground", "chocolate4",
                                  "font", "Sans Bold",
                                  "paragraph-background", "lightgoldenrod",
                                  "scale", 1.15, NULL);
    mom_tag_idstart =
      gtk_text_buffer_create_tag (mom_obtextbuf,
                                  "idstart",
                                  "font", "Courier Bold",
                                  "foreground", "darkgreen", NULL);
```

I am not happy with that approach, and I would like these tags to have an appearance (font, size, colors) described in some external textual file (and likewise for the widgets around the textviews).

So my question is:

**How to customize `GtkTextTag`-s thru GTK CSS stylesheets?**

I was thinking of creating some "fake" [GtkWidgetPath](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk3-GtkWidgetPath.html) (should I create one such path per gtk text tag) and using it to retrieve the style information in the GTK CSS but I am not sure at all it is the right approach.

I also don't understand exactly how two different text views showing the *same* text buffers can have different styles for the same text (I hope it is not possible, but I am not sure why).

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8946016/841108) might be a related question, but it looks quite different to mine.

PS. I am not specifically focused on GTK3 CSS, but I do want to have if possible one single text file describing the appearance of my entire GTK3 application.

Comment: [GtkTextTagTable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextTagTable.html) implements GtkBuildable, so you could define the tags in the GtkBuilder UI definition language, load it using [gtk_builder_new_from_file](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-new-from-file), pick just the GtkTextTagTable from it using [gtk_builder_get_object](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-new-from-file), and supply it to [gtk_text_buffer_new()](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-new). That isn't CSS, though.

Comment: @NominalAnimal: Do you have an example of how to write that `.ui` file for GtkBuildable ?

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question, as suggested by [Nominal Animal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1475978/nominal-animal) in a comment, for future reference, it is not possible to use CSS, but possible with UI builder (The actual working code is in C++ and using GtkMM libgtkmm & GTK 3.22, i.e. on my github [melt-monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor) master branch git commit [d947aedc723913789515](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor/commit/d947aedc723913789515b3a8ce3357bc6f054230)). Indeed using (the GtkMM equivalent of) [gtk_builder_new_from_file](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-new-from-file) (passing `"browsermom.ui"` which is the path of the XML GTK UI file below) to get a GtkBuilder, fetching the `GtkTextTagTable` from it using [gtk_builder_get_object](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkBuilder.html#gtk-builder-get-object), supplying it to the `GtkTextBuffer` with [gtk_text_buffer_new](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#gtk-text-buffer-new).

Here is the XML GTK UI file `browsermom.ui` that I am using

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- file browsermom.ui for GtkBuilder describing tags in browsing textview -->
<!-- see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/39466395/841108 -->
<interface>
    <requires lib="gtk+" version="3.22"/>
    <object class='GtkTextTagTable' id='browsertagtable_id'>
      <!-- page_title_tag for the entire page -->
        <child type="tag">
            <object class='GtkTextTag'>
                <property name="name">page_title_tag</property>
                <property name="font">Arial Bold</property>
                <property name="scale">1.35</property>
                <property name="paragraph-background">lemonchiffon1</property>
                <property name="pixels-above-lines">3</property>
                <property name="pixels-below-lines">6</property>
                <property name="foreground">navyblue</property>
                <property name="justification">GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER</property>
            </object>
        </child>
      <!-- object_title_tag for start of object -->
        <child type="tag">
            <object class='GtkTextTag'>
                <property name="name">object_title_tag</property>
                <property name="font">Cabin Medium</property>
                <property name="scale">1.27</property>
                <property name="paragraph-background">cornsilk</property>
                <property name="pixels-above-lines">2</property>
                <property name="pixels-below-lines">3</property>
                <property name="foreground">navyblue</property>
                <property name="justification">GTK_JUSTIFY_CENTER</property>
            </object>
        </child>
 <!-- etc.... --->
 </object>
</interface>
```

<sup>(the tricky part was to understand that the `<child` XML tags need a `type="tag"` XML attribute)</sup>

BTW, for some reason I don't understand, I'm getting GTk warnings like

```
(monimelt:25323): Gtk-WARNING **: Failed to set property gtkmm__GtkTextTag.scale to O.9: Could not parse double 'O.9'
```

even if `0.9` does not appear in that file.

Comment: Nice example to have for future reference. The `child` tag format surprised me too, but it *is* explicitly mentioned in the [GtkTextTagTable](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextTagTable.html) documentation.

Comment: And understanding that `<child` tags are needed was not intuitive neither.